# Background color from HTML5 colorpicker

Tags: javascript, html, color-picker

How i can change background color automatically with HTML5 colorpicker?
Currently after i have selected my color, i have to click button to change the background color. I tried to use while (1) loop to change it automatically, but it just crashes my browser.

https://jsfiddle.net/VortexP/eh4t17fv/4/

```
HTML:
<input type="button" id="fullscreenbutton" onclick="fcolor()"> Button
<br>
<input type="color" id="colorpickerbutton" name="color"> Colorpicker
<br>
<div id="overlay" ></div>Result

JAVASCRIPT:
function fcolor () {
var color = document.getElementById("colorpickerbutton").value;
document.getElementById("overlay").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the `while(1)` loop crashes your browser is because JavaScript is single-threaded. That means all of your JavaScript runs sequentially. You can never have two JavaScript functions running at the exact same time.

So, `while(1)` blocks all of your other JavaScript from executing, and even freezes the webpage itself because it blocks all browser events.

What you want to do is call a function only when the color input changes :)

That would look like this:

HTML:
`<input type="color" id="colorpickerbutton" name="color" onChange="changeColor(this.value)">`

JavaScript:

```
function changeColor(newColor) {
     document.getElementById("overlay").style.backgroundColor = newColor;
}
```

Comment: +1 for explanation, but -1 for inline JavaScript, which should be avoided because of bad practice / separation of code.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any infinite while loops. You need to attack an eventListener to yout input.

```
<input type="color" id="colorPickerButton" name="color">

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.body.style.background = this.value;
});
```